# How to get Access to auto save my VBA code changes

Tags: ms-access, vba, autosave

I'm fed up with Access crashing after I've written and run some code and forgot to manually save it and hence all the new code is gone. How can I get Access to automatically save my VBA code upon, say, compile or run? I don't see any settings in VBA and I don't see any answers to a Google search. (Also, I don't think I've faced this problem in any other IDE.)

Comment: There is no 'auto save' option in Access. I have experienced your pain many times, but once you solve the cause of the crash, you are way ahead! I just learned to be excessive in clicking Save and making backup copies each day.

Comment: When you close Access, it asks if you want to save the current changes. Of course, if you click no, they are gone. So click Yes. Or just make it a habit to compile and save whenever you feel for it.

Comment: If you're running the kind of code that could potentially crash Access (e.g. looping / recursion / requesting a lot of memory), surely getting in to the habit of saving before running would be a good thing to start doing? Ctrl + S and then F5.. easy-peasy.

Comment: For a while I was working on VBA code that liked to crash a lot and lose my code. I started to add `DoCmd.Save` to the beginning of the procedures so the DB saved itself every time the code ran while I was developing it.